# Formula to Provide Total for Numbers Combined with Text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]I am having problems getting a total from a row of cells that contain both numbers and text, I have tried a couple of different formulas now and they don't fix it.

I have 5 cells in a row which reference a sum total in a separate workbook which I then add text on to: 
='K:\Folder 1\Surveys\Returned Surveys[00001.xlsm]00001'!$D$15 & "/18"

At first my had just =SUM(K4:O4) but this just returned 5 instead of the sum total of the row.

I then tried to find the number within the text with the following formula:
=LEFT(FIND("/",K4)-1+(FIND("/",L4)-1+(FIND("/",M4)-1+(FIND("/",N4)-1+(FIND("/",O4))))))-1
However, this just returns #VALUE.

In a last ditch attempt I tried to convert the values into text and then add them but this also just returns the number of cells rather than the total value:
=TEXT(K4,0)&"/18" and then the above =LEFT formula.

Comment: I cannot easily reproduce your problem from the data you have provided. Please read [How to provide a minimum, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in Help.  A copy or screenshot of your data and desired output would be useful

Comment: I have added a screenshot, my formula is linked to a separate workbook and it refers to a cell which is a sum total of a number of cells. I want to add the text "/18" or "/12" as the total number of is out of 18 or 12 and then in the final column I want to add the total number of those together.

Comment: That is good.  I see you now have an answer that works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your 5 cells and use a simple equals formula in each. Example:

```
='K:\Folder 1\Surveys\Returned Surveys[00001.xlsm]00001'!$D$15
```

With the five cells selected, tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. When the Format Cells dialog opens, go to the Number tab. Choose Custom from the list down the left and supply the following for the *Type:*,

```
0\/18
```

... or,

```
0\/12
```

Click <kbd>OK</kbd>. Your numbers will *look* like they have **/12** or **/18** tacked on the right side but the underlying values are still the raw numbers from the external workbook. Sum them using any conventional means you want (r.g. `=SUM(K4:O4)` or `=K4+L4+M4+N4+O4`).

Your formula would have worked as,

```
=LEFT(K4, FIND("/", K4)-1)+LEFT(L4, FIND("/", L4)-1)+LEFT(M4, FIND("/", M4)-1)+LEFT(N4, FIND("/", N4)-1)+LEFT(O4, FIND("/", O4)-1)
```

The following image shows your method (concatenate then split) in row 4 and mine (custom number format and sum) in row 5.

[image: Custom number format and concatenated suffix]

Text defaults to left-alignment and true numbers default to right-alignment.

Comment: That is perfect, thank you so much you've been a great help!!

Comment: Glad to hear you got sorted out. For my own curiosity, which method did you up going with?

Comment: I went with the first option, I didn't know you could do that, it will help cut down on the amount of formulas in the workbook too.